# How to keep multi-line display while editing Shiny dataTable?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I have a dataTable in R Shiny (running the latest version 0.8). Each row contains a long, milti-line description. There is no problem while displaying the content in multiple lines. I am able to make the dataTable editable by using editable = T argument while rendering the DataTable. However, when I am trying to edit the description, the row contracts to display the content in a single line. It then becomes very difficult to find the exact location for making the edits. Is there a way to keep the multi-line display while editing the dataTable?

### UI

```r
DTOutput(outputId = "table1")
```

### Server

```r
##My Code
 output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(expr =  ingredient_input(), server = T,
                            editable = T,
                            style = "bootstrap",
                            escape = F,
                            colnames = c("EAN number", "Ingredients"),
                            caption = HTML('<b>Uploaded ingredient file</b>')
                            )
```

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/671